# Immutable reference after mutable borrow

Tags: rust

I run into similar problems related to ownership/borrowing every time I use Rust, so here is the simplest piece of code that illustrates my usual problems:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Res {
    name: String,
}

impl Res {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Res {
        Res {
            name: name.to_string(),
        }
    }

    // I don't need all_res to be mutable
    fn normalize(&mut self, all_res: &Vec<Res>) {
        // [...] Iterate through all_res and update self.name
        self.name = "foo".to_string();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let res = RefCell::new(vec![Res::new("res1"), Res::new("res2")]);

    for r in res.borrow_mut().iter_mut() {
        // This panics at runtime saying it's
        // already borrowed (which makes sense, I guess).
        r.normalize(&*res.borrow());
    }
}
```

After reading about [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) I thought this would work. It compiles, but panics at runtime.

How do I reference a vector while iterating over the same vector? Is there any better data structure to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program panics because you're trying to borrow the `Vec` mutably and immutably at the same time: this is not allowed.

What you need to do instead is wrap only the `String`s in `RefCell`. This allows you to mutate the strings while iterating the `Vec`.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Res {
    name: RefCell<String>,
}

impl Res {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Res {
        Res {
            name: RefCell::new(name.to_string()),
        }
    }

    // I don't need all_res to be mutable
    fn normalize(&self, all_res: &Vec<Res>) {
        // [...] Iterate through all_res and update self.name
        *self.name.borrow_mut() = "foo".to_string();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let res = vec![Res::new("res1"), Res::new("res2")];

    for r in res.iter() {
        r.normalize(&res);
    }

    println!("{}", *res[0].name.borrow());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help - I'm still quite lost in the Rust ownership rules. I guess I'll try to develop a simple mark-and-sweep garbage collector to practice those rules.

Comment: @user3696012: *I guess I'll try to develop a simple mark-and-sweep garbage collector to practice those rules.* => Try to avoid opening the `unsafe` hatch, it's hard enough when you understand the ownership rules, but if you have not internalize them already...